# X11 font could not be loaded in R

Tags: r, debian-based

Im running into some issues plotting in R. I keep getting the error:
Error in grid.Call(C_stringMetric, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)) :
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 9 could not be loaded.

It even gives this error when i specify a different font in my ggplot function.
The X11fonts() function also doesnt seem to help.
Im currently running on debian 12, and Helvetica is installed in

> fc-list | grep -i "helvetica
> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfonts/Helvetica.ttf: Helvetica:style=Regular
> I really have no clue how to fix this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.